# Profiling C++/CLI NUnit tests

Tags: visual-studio-2012, c++-cli, nunit, profiling

Is it possible to profile C++/CLI NUnit tests with Visual Studio 2012?

The Profiler always wants to have an Executable.

Comment: Any reason you can't profile the NUnit test runner?

Comment: More specifically, the NUnit console runner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is possible. The testrunner is attachable for debugging.